# What is the syntax for a LINQ filter for List<string>?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a C# program using EF Core.

I fetch my records like this:

```
List<MyEntity> candidateRecords = await myFilters.ToListAsync();
```

I build my filters like this:

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> myFilters = from m in context.MyEntity
                                 select m;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criterion1))
   myFilters = myFilters.Where(s => s.SomeColumn.Contains(criterion1));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criterion2))
   myFilters = myFilters.Where(s => s.SomeColumn.Contains(criterion2));
   ...
```

This all works.  I can select on any combination of criteria for single values, e.g. `criterion s.Color = "Blue"`.

But what's the syntax for filtering on all matches of a *LIST*?

EXAMPLE (doesn't work correctly):

```
  List<string> selectedNames = new List<string>() {"Huey", "Dewey", "Louie"}:
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criterionX)) 
  {
       myFilters = myFilters.Where(
         record => selectedNames.Contains(record.Name));
       ...
```

Let's say there are multiple records for all three names.  The above example will only return the records for "Huey"; no records are returned for "Dewey" or "Louie".

**Question:**

What is the correct LINQ syntax to return *ALL* the matching records for *EVERY* name in the list?

Comment: `selectedNames.Contains(record.Name)` looks right to me.  Can you write a repro for "no records returned" behavior you mentioned?  I don't see why you don't get matches for "Dewey" or "Louie".

Comment: `.Where(x => someList.Contains(x.SomeValue))` is indeed the right approach, so I suspect something else may be wrong in your testing/validation.  How exactly are you confirming this?

Comment: does `select * from M Record where Record.Name in ('Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie') ` look correct and return the correct results? *in SQL*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to get something equivalent to the original

```
 myFilters = myFilters.Where(s => s.SomeColumn.Contains(criterion1));
```

just with a list of criteria.

Then it should be something like this

```
myFilters = myFilters
    .Where(record => 
        selectedNames
            .Any(selectedName => 
                 record.Name.Contains(selectedName)));
```

with the [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) extension method.

Comment: FYI, the original LINQ, `selectedNames.Contains(record.Name)` was correct.  The problem was actually some unrelated issues related to how "name" got entered into the database.

Comment: @FoggyDay You can add your own answer, explain the issue there and mark it as the answer. Though with such "external issue" questions probably neither mine nor your answer will unfortunately be of much use to the future readers, at least that's nice that you've found the source of the problem. P.S.: Can also recommend to add  "test cases"/[mcve] to your future questions - they often helped me to diagnose the issue with my own code without posting/simplified the task for those who tried to answer such questions when posted.